# How to disable push notification permissions in Google Play Games Services on iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have implemented Google Play Game Services in a Unity game. I have got build and deploy working to iOS but I get a permissions request for push notifications on first run, and iTunes connect says my app requests push notification access.

I have no need for push notifications and haven't implmented them on purpose, and have no multiplayer implemented in the game. So I'm assuming this is an automatic thing in GPGS? Can I disable it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have got around this now by commenting out the following lines in the file GPGSAppController.mm, which I believe register the app for notifications.

```
/*
  // iOS 8 Notifications
  if ([application
       respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:
     [UIUserNotificationSettings
      settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
                        UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
      categories:nil]];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
  } else {
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
  }
*/
//gpg::TryHandleNotificationFromLaunchOptions(launchOptions);
//gpg::RegisterDeviceToken(deviceToken, GPGPushNotificationEnvironmentProduction);
```

After testing all the GPGS features I need still work but I don't get a push notifications permission pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

**From the docs on the GitHub [page](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity):**

This plugin can be disabled for building on iOS. What this means is that the libraries and references originating in the GooglePlayGames namespace are excluded from the build. It does not affect code that has been written by you, such as calls to the GPGS API.

To disable the Google Play Game Services in the iOS build, open the iOS player settings. Then in the "Other Settings" panel, find the entry named "Scripting Define Symbol" and add a symbol named: NO_GPGS (case sensitive).

Comment: Project won't build with this define. Also I don't want to disable the plugin, I still want to use it for leaderboards and saves etc. I just don't need the notification permission request.

Answer (score -1):

1. Find the `xxx.entitlements` file in your Xcode project
2. Remove the key `aps-environment`